# android: my WakefulBroadcastReceiver class doesn't work after adding Static fields to my class

Tags: android-studio

I'm writing an Android application which has to be booted on start up. I extended a class called "WakeFulBootCompletedIntentReceiver" from "WakefulBroadcastReceiver" to catch the boot completed event. the class works fine just only before adding static fields/methods.
I mean the below code:

```
public class WakeFulBootCompletedIntentReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    public static boolean PoweredOn=false;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
        PoweredOn=true;
        System.out.println("Action Boot Completed :)0");
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction()))
            System.out.println("Action Boot NEWW :)");
    }
```

}

works fine. But by using this one:

```
public class WakeFulBootCompletedIntentReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    public static boolean PoweredOn=false;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
    PoweredOn=true;
    System.out.println("Action Boot Completed :)0");
    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction()))
        System.out.println("Action Boot NEWW :)");
}

public static void  Show(String text)
{
  System.out.println(text+" in Wakeful");
  Toast.makeText(text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

my app doesn't start after boot completing.

what is the reason in your opinion.